# Taurus evaluate pass/fail criteria on Jmeter Apdex

Tags: jmeter, taurus, apdex

I was wondering if there was a way to have Taurus report overall test failure on a bad apdex score.

ie. Currently we can do `avg-rt of login>1s, continue as failed`
But can we do something like `apdex of login>.85, stop fail`, if any apdex score is less than .85 or something we choose, stop the test.

I am able to get it working with jmeter .jmx scripts and samplers but I'm wondering how far I can go with Taurus and Jmeter when it comes to pass/fail criteria for testing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Taurus documentation](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) the possible metrics are:

- `avg-rt` - average response time, e.g. avg-rt>2s500ms.
- `avg-lt`- average latency, e.g. avg-lt for my-label>2.
- `avg-ct` - average connect time, e.g. avg-ct>100ms.
- `stdev-rt` - standard deviation for full response time, e.g. stdev-rt>0.5.
- `p`... - percentile timing, e.g. p90>1s for 10s, p99.9>10s, stop as failed.
- `hits` - number of responses, e.g. hits for my-label>100 for 5s, stop as non-failed.
- `bytes` - response data size, e.g. bytes for my-label>10MB, possible types are B, kB and MB.
- `succ` or `success` - successful responses, supports percentage threshold, e.g. succ<100% .
- `fail` or `failures` - failed responses, supports percentage threshold, e.g. failures>50% for 5s, stop as failed.
- `rc`... - percentage of specific responce code amount of all requests. Response code may be specified using wildcards ? and *, e.g. rc500>20 for 5s, stop as failed, rc4??>20%, rc*>=10 for 1m, rcException>99% for 1m, continue as failed.

You can reach out to Taurus developers and maintainers via [Taurus support forum](https://groups.google.com/g/codename-taurus) and ask to include your "apdex" metric into pass/fail criteria or if you're a BlazeMeter customer you can open a [support request](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket) to do this as a priority, but for the time being it's not supported

Answer (score 0):

That’s not possible as taurus bases its failure criteria on its own computed metrics.

Apdex is not one of those.